# Reading text file into array in perl

Tags: perl

```
    my $file = '/var/tmp/temp_data.txt';      ##################### File for reading
    open(FILE, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) || die("Unable to open file");
    my @fieldss = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);
    chomp @fieldss;

    my @fields = split(':', @fieldss);####################### Splitting the lines in file ##############
####################################### Dereference ############################
    my $names = $fields[0];
    my $rate = $fields[1];
    my $no_of_days = $fields[2];
    my $total_salary = $fields[3];
    my $total = $fields[4];
    my $basic = $fields[5];
    my $da = $fields[6];
    my $hra = $fields[7];
    my $ot_hallowance = $fields[8];
    my $gross = $fields[9];
    my $epf = $fields[10];
    my $nett = $fields[11];

    print "$names\n $rate\n";

        foreach $names (@fields) {
                my $dbh = "DBI:$platform:$database:$host:$port";
                my $connect = DBI->connect($dbh, $user, $pw) || die $DBI::errstr;
                $query = "SELECT * FROM salary WHERE name IN('sssss', 'ffffff', 'dddddd', 'ddededed', 'garaead', 'adgfdfg', 'gadfredg')";
                my $sth = $connect->prepare($query);
                $sth->execute() || die $DBI::errstr;

                my @data2;
                while (@data2 = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
                    my $name = $data2[0];
                    my $email = $data2[1];

                        if ($names eq $name) {  ######################### Comparing names in file and database ########################
```

The above code is to read the text file and data get split using split function. My problem is I am making mistake at reading and splitting the file. I got 504 error while running the code, I think it is because of calling the database for every line in text file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use bareword filehandles. It's not 1999 anymore.

Comment: `split(':', @fieldss)` doesn't split the lines in the file. `split` takes a single string, not an array. What did you expect this to do?

Comment: What's in the error log of your web server?

Comment: I changed the bareword filehandle to $fh it gives GLOB(0x321ace8) in browser

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /var/www/cgi-bin/filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to see what the data in your input file looks like. But there are certainly some strange things going on in your code. The major problem seems to be this line:

```
my @fields = split(':', @fieldss);
```

`split()` takes two scalar arguments - a regex to split on and a string to split. It is, therefore, evaluating `@fieldss` in scalar context and getting the number of elements in the array. This will, of course, be an integer, which won't contain a colon. This leads to `@fields` containing a single element which is the number of elements in `@fieldss`. This example illustrates that:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = qw[1:foo 2:bar 3:baz];

my @arr2 = split /:/, @arr;

say Dumper @arr2;
```

The output I get is:

```
$VAR1 = '3';
```

Your code to set up `@fields` should probably be more like this:

```
my $file = '/var/tmp/temp_data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
  # Note: Added filename and error code to output.
  || die("Unable to open $file: $!");

my @fields;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  push @fields, split /:/;
}
close $fh;
```

I haven't looked at the rest of your code in great detail, but it certainly raises some questions. Your copying of the array into individual variables is probably pointless, but can be achieved in a single statement:

```
my ($names, $rate, $no_of_days, $total_salary, $total,
    $basic, $da, $hra, $ot_hallowance, $gross, $epf,
    $nett) = @fields;
```

But then you iterate over `@fields`, seemingly assuming that each element is a name. Perhaps you need to explain what you're doing in greater detail.

None of this, however, explains the 504 status code you are getting. You mention that you are running the database query for every row in the text file. It's certainly true that you are exactly the same query on each iteration of your loop - and that would seem to be very wasteful (just run it once and store the results in a variable) but, as we've determined that  `@fields` can only ever contain a single element, your loop only runs once and you only query the database once.

This probably isn't, strictly speaking, an answer to your question. But your question leaves so many things unexplained that it's impossible to answer. Hopefully, this will give you some insight into how you could, at least, improve your program to the extent that we could then start to address the real issues that are currently hidden.

**Update:** I've just realised what the structure of your input file is. You probably want to read it into an array of hashes using code like this:

```
my $file = '/var/tmp/temp_data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
  # Note: Added filename and error code to output.
  || die("Unable to open $file: $!");

my @records; # Terrible variable name!
my @cols = qw[names rate no_of_days total_salary total basic da
              hra ot_hallowance gross epf nett];

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my %rec;
  @rec{@cols} = split /:/;
  push @records, \%rec;
}
```

Comment: `J. XXXXXX:17000:30:17000:11900:9520:2380:3400:1700:17000:1428:15572:
S. XXXXX:15000:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:
K. XXXXXX:12000:30:12000:8400:6720:1680:2400:1200:12000:1008:10992:
A. XXXXX:9000:27:8100:5670:4536:1134:1620:810:8100:680:7420:
S. XXXXX:9000:30:9000:6300:5040:1260:1800:900:9000:756:8244:
I. XXXXX:9000:26:7800:5460:4368:1092:1560:780:7800:655:7145:
J. XXXXX:8000:29:7733:5413:4330:1083:1547:773:7733:650:7083:
X. XXXXX:8000:26:6933:4853:3882:971:1387:693:6933:582:6351:`

My input file

Comment: @prakashg: Dumping data in a comment like that isn't at all helpful. Please edit your question to add this. You could also take the opportunity to explain more about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what you file looks like. But I've done this type of thing before in reading Protein Data Bank (PDB) files into an array, and then splitting them by the columns which are separated my whitespace. I can't guarantee my code will work because I don't even have your file, but anyway the question is how do you read in a file and then split it up into columns is the question, yeah ...

Your split isn't working because you aren't splitting on however your columns are separated which is probably a comma or at least one white-space. But I've never seen columns in a file separated by a colon like you say. Also, yes you can read the file into an array, but to get all the columns as scalars for each row I think you need to keep doing that in a loop or else you have an individual value for each column that wouldn't extend throughout all the file. Okay, you are really splitting on a colon. I am sorry about the hassle. Please forgive me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Program Description: _________ 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say'; # say is like print, but you don't need to type \n.

my $file = '/var/tmp/temp_data.txt';      ##################### File for reading
my $filehandle; # Just like your bareword filehandle FILE. 
my @fields = (); # My use of fields is the same as yours. 
open($filehandle, '<', $file) or die "Could not open file $_ because $!";

my @All_Lines = <$filehandle>; # This is just everything in the file ... all lines. 
my $line; # Our current line which will be useful for the split. 
close $filehandle;

# We will declare all of our variables outside of a loop
# That we split all the columns of the file on on colon.
# ... declaring our variables now so they don't get locked in our loop. 
my $names;
my $rate;
my $no_of_days;
my $total_salary;
my $total;
my $basic;
my $da;
my $hra;
my $ot_hallowance;
my $gross;
my $epf;
my $nett;

# Iterating over ever line of the file in a foreach loop. 
foreach $line (@All_Lines)
{

     @fields = split(':', $line); # splitting on a colon. 

$names = $fields[0];
$rate = $fields[1];
$no_of_days = $fields[2];
$total_salary = $fields[3];
$total = $fields[4];
$basic = $fields[5];
$da = $fields[6];
$hra = $fields[7];
$ot_hallowance = $fields[8];
$gross = $fields[9];
$epf = $fields[10];
$nett = $fields[11];

say "$names $rate";

# Then I'm pretty sure that I can dump the rest of your code here
# And you should because @fields is now within this foreach loop. It doesn't exist anywhere else. 
# I'm pretty sure I'm justified in removing your foreach loop here
# Because in mine, the column of names will be read and operated on line by line. 
# Also, your goal was to iterate over $names with a foreach loop
# which I'm doing right now, but where are you operating on it? 

       # Perhaps you should declare these variables with "my" before we start looping through all the lines of the file one line at a time.
       # But I think you will be okay having them here. 
        my $dbh = "DBI:$platform:$database:$host:$port";
        my $connect = DBI->connect($dbh, $user, $pw) || die $DBI::errstr;
        # You didn't declare query with "my $query". I think you should, especially since I classically enabled "use strict". 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM salary WHERE name IN('sssss', 'ffffff', 'dddddd', 'ddededed', 'garaead', 'adgfdfg', 'gadfredg')";
        my $sth = $connect->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute() || die $DBI::errstr;

         my @data2;
         # So @data2 gets formed when you start the while loop, right?
        while (@data2 = $sth->fetchrow_array()) 
                {
                    my $name = $data2[0];
                    my $email = $data2[1];

                        if ($names eq $name) 
                        {
                              ######################### Comparing names in file and database ######################## 
                        } # This bracket ends your if conditional
                } # This bracket ends your while loop.

} # This bracket ends my foreach loop that you want to stay within. 

# Note: Commenting where brackets begin and end can be really useful when you are trying to stay within a loop.
```

Note: I tested the split based on one or more whitespace on a file
which is a PDB file that looks like this separated by one or more white-spaces, and the each column of the PDB file can be isolated line by line, so I'm pretty sure this will work on your file.

```
ATOM     38  CB  PHE A   7      15.240  41.685  54.772  1.00 10.03           C
ATOM     39  CG  PHE A   7      15.740  42.936  54.063  1.00 12.39           C
ATOM     40  CD1 PHE A   7      15.096  44.166  54.328  1.00 11.59           C
ATOM     41  CD2 PHE A   7      16.851  42.864  53.189  1.00 10.59           C
ATOM     42  CE1 PHE A   7      15.540  45.310  53.626  1.00 12.79           C
ATOM     43  CE2 PHE A   7      17.329  44.058  52.581  1.00 13.07           C
ATOM     44  CZ  PHE A   7      16.651  45.259  52.776  1.00 12.33           C
ATOM    156  CG  GLU A  20      14.635  48.596  50.249  1.00  9.28           C
ATOM    157  CD  GLU A  20      15.173  49.229  51.481  1.00 10.96           C
ATOM    158  OE1 GLU A  20      15.790  50.279  51.395  1.00 11.04           O
ATOM    159  OE2 GLU A  20      14.851  48.625  52.550  1.00 13.31           O
```

Now, I usually close a file way later in the program, but yes you are right. You can glob save it into an array and operate on that array line by line even after you have closed the file.

Comment: *But I've never seen columns in a file separated by a colon like you say* Have you never looked at the `/etc/passwd` file on a Linux system?

Comment: What is this "Diagnostics" module? There's no module called "Diagnostics" on CPAN. There's [diagnostics](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/lib/diagnostics.pm), of course, but no-one needs to install that from CPAN as it has been part of the standard Perl distribution for over twenty years.

Comment: *Your split isn't working because you aren't splitting on however your columns are separated* No. His split isn't working as he is trying to split an array.

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't say what I meant about the split. Anyway, you are right. As you can see when I perform the split I do it on a scalar of the elements of each line of the file, and save it into an array which totally works. I think the Diagnostics module exists because when I check it with perldoc Diagnostics I get this:

NAME
    diagnostics, splain - produce verbose warning diagnostics

SYNOPSIS
    Using the "diagnostics" pragma: ### ect ...

Comment: Hmm, maybe importing Diagnostics is the same as importing diagnostics and it's not case sensitive because I get no error on my system when I ask for use Diagnostics in a perl script.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I believe the Windows filesystem is (astonishingly!) still case-insensitive. But it's a bad idea to share case-insensitive code on a public site like this - most people will be running it on case-sensitive platforms and your code will fail.

Comment: The original poster is clearly working on Linux or Unix (see his reference to `/var/tmp`), so your code will just give a syntax error for him.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that I made a typographical error. Thank you for correcting me on it. I appreciate it. Whoops!

Comment: And anyway, you shouldn't encourage people to use `diagnostics` without explaining why they need to remove it from production code.

Comment: What exactly is so bad about this diagnostics module?

Comment: Your comment still makes no sense. There is never any need to install `diagnostics.pm` from CPAN.

Comment: *What exactly is so bad about this diagnostics module?* Not bad exactly, but it fills up error logs with too much detail. I've seen filesystems fill up because of it. Just stick with `use warnings` in production and add `use diagnostics` if necessary in development.